# Best Method for Organizing NSLog Statements for Large Project

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, logging

I am curious what other people are doing for organizing NSLog statements in large project. I have worked with more complex logging frameworks for Java, Flex, etc... that allow for some methods of doing this, but I haven't seen anything for logging within an iOS / OS X application.

For example, there are specific 'logging levels' within log4j that allow you to assign log messages to groups (for example: informational logs, warning logs, error logs, etc...).  This is helpful because you can determine what level actually gets output to the console.  If you only need to see the error logs, you aren't bombarded with a bunch of extra log statements.

Is there any built-in mechanism for this, or are there any third party frameworks that do this?  (I want to be clear here - this isn't the only thing I am looking for.  I would be very interested in hearing how people handle this issue and others related to logging on a larger Objective-C project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a header file I found at http://brenwill.com/2010/flexible-ios-logging/

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I am looking for.  It is a simple implementation that is unintrusive (for the most part).  Great find!

Answer (score 2):

Apple has its own C logging facility called [asl](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/asl.3.html) (Apple System Log) which seems to do some of what you want.  I also managed to find one currently maintained Objective-C logging framework called [CocoaLumberjack](http://code.google.com/p/cocoalumberjack/), however, I have never used it myself.

Comment: CocoaLumberjack looks awesome.  It is a bit more than I need - but a great find.

Comment: @dtuckernet:  Yes, I discovered it while researching the answer to your question.  I think I'm going to try it too.